# How to change niceness of process by name

Tags: bash, cron, process, nice

Java process is killing my computer (Intel i3, 8GB RAM). It takes over whole CPU and system starts to hang. I was trying to change `niceness` of java processes but i have to control it for all time and this is not always possible. So for beginning I tried to construct a command to change process `niceness` by name. Ended up with something like this:

```
ps ax -o pid,comm | grep java | awk '{print $1}' | tr "\n" " " | renice -n 5 -p
```

But it looks like it doesn't work. And I don't know where to go next. Bash script maybe? Run it by `cron` or by `watch` every `x` time? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have only one `java` instance running, simply:

```
renice -n 5 -p $(pgrep ^java$)
```

- `$(pgrep ^java$)`: command substitution; `bash` replaces this with the output of `pgrep ^java$`; `pgrep ^java$` returns the list of PIDs of the processes whose name matches the regular expression `^java$`, which matches all processes whose name is exactly `java`

If you have multiple `java` instances running:

```
for p in $(pgrep ^java$); do renice -n 5 -p $p; done
```

- `for p in $(pgrep ^java$); do renice -n 5 -p $p; done`: almost the same as above; `$(pgrep ^java$)` is a command substitution; `bash` replaces this with the output of `pgrep ^java$`; `pgrep ^java$` returns the list of PIDs of the processes whose name matches the regular expression `^java$`, which matches all processes whose name is exactly `java`; this is expanded into the `for` loop, which assigns a new line of the output of `pgrep ^java$` to the variable `$p` and runs `renice -n 5 -p $p` at each iteration until the output of `pgrep ^java$` is consumed

Comment: That works pretty well. But to take next step, what is better to run this periodically. Some cron or watch command?

Comment: The first command is also working, if you have one single program running multiple processes (like a parallel processing thread pool in MATLAB).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
pgrep java | xargs -n 1 echo renice -n 5 -p
```

If output is okay, remove `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

After all I occured it was memory problem. I didn't set maximum memory for Jetty so it tried to allocate 1/4 of all memory. Also I have found final solution for such problems here:

[OOM killer not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398236/oom-killer-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found is using the `pidof` command:

`renice <new niceness> -p $(pidof <process name>)`

found from: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4614/renice-by-name

For your situation, probably put that command into `crontab -e` (as root) with whatever period you want (say every 30 mins). It seems like you should find the root cause of your new and resource-hogging java processes and see if you can fix/prevent that.